# Fiware IDM : Dynamic permission resource

Tags: fiware, xacml, abac, fiware-wilma, authzforce

I've deployed an application based on Fiware generic enablers, in Docker. The versions are:

- Orion 1.14
- Cygnus 1.9.0
- Authzforce 5.4.1
- Keyrock: the latest
- Pep-proxy: 7.0.1

but, when I want to create a permission in keyrock I can't find a specific syntax or character sequence to enter a dynamic resource in the resource field like: `/resource1/<user>/info`, or to specify only the resource prefix like: `/resource2/<whatever>`.

[image: dynamic resource example]

Really exists the syntax for the  dynamic resource and authzforce can create  a permissions asociated  to a dynamic resource or is necessary create a XACML rule?

Comment: This is not currently supported using verb/resource format. You could implement it configuring an advanced XACML rule

Comment: Good luck with that! There is virtually no documentation about that in the Fiware community.

You can start looking for how Fiware IdM stores the Verb + PATH rules in Authzforce (because it actually converts each of these rules into XACML policies, at least that's how it worked when it was based on the Openstack Keystone project) and then generates your own XACML policy. I'm sorry I can't help you much more than this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is necessary to create an Advanced XACML Rule. For example, you may look at the [XACML Rule template](https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/blob/master/lib/authzforce_templates/rule.ejs) in the IDM source code, which is used to generate a basic Rule (for a static resource path); you would have to customize it (besides removing the template code `<%...%>`), especially modify the Target and the Condition elements (use XACML function string-concatenate to create the string `/resource1/{param}/info` dynamically).

Another difficulty is to get the `{param}` value in the PEP, and make sure it is sent in the XACML Request to AuthzForce PDP. The Pep-proxy only gets/sends the following XACML attributes as you can see from the [Pep's Authzforce client code](https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy/blob/master/lib/azf.js) (names shortened for conciseness): resource-id, sub-resource-id, action-id, subject-role. Therefore, if you want the user-id as `{param}` for example, you have to modify the Pep code I just mentioned, i.e. extract the user ID from the `userInfo` variable and add the corresponding XACML Attribute (subject-id) in the Request. Or use your own Pep and do whatever you want of course.